# Point Symbolizer() in rundemo.cpp file Giving error

Tags: mapnik, c++, data

The code is given Below:

```
roads2_rule_11.append(point_symbolizer("abc.png"));
```

The error is given below:

```
rundemo.cpp: In function âint main(int, char**)â:
```

rundemo.cpp:142:57: error: no matching function for call to âmapnik::point_symbolizer::point_symbolizer(const char [8])â
rundemo.cpp:142:57: note: candidates are:
/usr/local/include/mapnik/point_symbolizer.hpp:47:5: note: mapnik::point_symbolizer::point_symbolizer(const mapnik::point_symbolizer&)
/usr/local/include/mapnik/point_symbolizer.hpp:47:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst char [8]â to âconst mapnik::point_symbolizer&â
/usr/local/include/mapnik/point_symbolizer.hpp:46:5: note: mapnik::point_symbolizer::point_symbolizer(mapnik::path_expression_ptr)
/usr/local/include/mapnik/point_symbolizer.hpp:46:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from âconst char [8]â to âmapnik::path_expression_ptr {aka boost::shared_ptr, mapnik::attribute> > >}â
/usr/local/include/mapnik/point_symbolizer.hpp:45:5: note: mapnik::point_symbolizer::point_symbolizer()

I have an image that i want to show at each point .How to input point_symbolizer()?